# Multiple histograms with non-integer frequencies in R using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to find a way to plot multiple histograms of non-integer frequencies in R. For example:

```
a = c(1,2,3,4,5)
a_freq = c(1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5)
b = c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10)
b_freq = c(2.5, 5, 6, 7, 8)
```

using something like

```
qplot(x = a, weight = a_freq, geom = "histogram")
```

works, but how do I superimpose b (and b_freq) onto this? any ideas?

This is what we would do if the frequencies are integer values:

```
require(ggplot2) 
require(reshape2) 
set.seed(1) 
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 5, sd = 2), y = rnorm(n = 1000,    mean = 2), z = rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 10)) 
ggplot(melt(df), aes(value, fill = variable)) + geom_histogram(position = "dodge")
```

Something similar, when we have non_integer values?

Thanks,
Karan

Comment: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/

Comment: Can you be more specific, please? People frequently confuse histograms with bar plots. Do you really mean a histogram or would a bar plot suffice? Do you really mean to "superimpose" them on _one_ graph? Some bars will be on top of each other. Should they be dodged next to each other? Alpha blending? Or would faceting them next to each other be ok? These are the sorts of the details that need to be in a good question.

Comment: Hey @joran here are the clarifications:

Comment: So yes, we want to dodge. Should be a histogram, not a a barplot.

Comment: Ok, but that's not a histogram. A histagram is a _binned_ continuous variable. You are plotting vertical bars of specified heights as discrete values (_not_ bins). That is a bar plot. It is a very common misconception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm still not entirely sure what you're trying to do, so here are four options:

```
library(ggplot2)

a = c(1,2,3,4,5)
a_freq = c(1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5)
b = c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10)
b_freq = c(2.5, 5, 6, 7, 8)

dat <- data.frame(x = c(a,b),
                                    freq = c(a_freq,b_freq),
                                    grp = rep(letters[1:2],each = 5))

ggplot(dat,aes(x = x,weight = freq,fill = grp)) + 
    geom_histogram(position = "dodge")

ggplot(dat,aes(x = x,y = freq,fill = grp)) + 
    geom_bar(position = "dodge",stat = "identity",width = 0.5)

ggplot(dat,aes(x = x,y = freq,fill = grp)) +
    facet_wrap(~grp) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity",width = 0.5)

ggplot() + 
    geom_bar(data = dat[dat$grp == 'a',],aes(x = x,y = freq),
                     fill = "blue",
                     alpha = 0.5,
                     stat = "identity",
                     width = 0.5) + 
    geom_bar(data = dat[dat$grp == 'b',],aes(x = x,y = freq),
                     fill = "red",
                     alpha = 0.5,
                     stat = "identity",
                     width = 0.5)
```

If you have a discrete `x` values and precomputed "heights" that is not a histogram, that is a bar plot, so I would opt for one of those.

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks so much.